# How to install a python package(PyXLL) correctly that is enclosed in a .zip file (that includes a bunch of different file formats)?

Tags: python, ubuntu, zip, installation, pyxll

I downloaded a .zip file to install the python [PyXLL](http://www.pyxll.com/download.html) package, using `sudo apt-get install PyXLL` or `sudo pip install PyXLL` doesn't work. Normally when you double click on a downloaded .zip that contains something to install in ubuntu it autoinstalls. But now it just opens the zip file that includes a bunch of different file formats. How do I install PyXLL correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyXXL does not provide a setup.py or a .deb in the ubuntu repositories. The best thing you can do is to add the .py in you [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) so that it can be found by import. If you want everyone to be able to use the code a good path to add it is in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages but first take a look at the [file system hierarchy standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) to decide where to place it.